# How to use the result of a thread with WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, inotifypropertychanged

Threads and Tasks are unfortunately a big mystery for me.

> Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject.

I am trying to avoid a freezing UI. My approach was doing work in a thread and setting properties later with output from the thread.
I've a base class for a **Job**. Basically it's a wrapper that starts a new thread with an **Input** and **Output** variable. I start a new thread, wait until the job is done and try to set it to my property **MyFoo**. But this won't work. See above quoted error message.

**How can I use a thread* without blocking the UI and set the result to an property in WPF?**
<sub>* I actually don't care if it is a thread, a task or whatever as long as it is not blocking my UI.</sub>

```
        // ...
        FooJob job = new FooJob {Input = input};
        job.Start();
        while (!job.IsDone) Wait(0.05);
        MyFoo = (BitmapSource) job.Output;
```

What I've tried is to set the output to my field instead of my Property and call **OnPropertyChanged** manually.

Here the actual wrapper class

```
public class Job {
    public object Output;
    public object Input;

    private bool _isDone;
    private readonly object _handle = new object();
    private Thread _thread;

    public bool IsDone {
        get {
            bool tmp;
            lock (_handle) {
                tmp = _isDone;
            }
            return tmp;
        }
        set {
            lock (_handle) {
                _isDone = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public virtual void Start() {
        _thread = new Thread(Run);
        _thread.Start();
    }

    protected virtual void ThreadFunction() {}

    private void Run() {
        ThreadFunction();
        IsDone = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Closed. See my answer in the duplicated question for a basic introduction on how to work with WPF UIs in a multi-threaded scenario. After reading that, if you have a specific question regarding a specific piece of WPF-related code, post a new question including that code and the relevant XAML.

Comment: Well, this throws the exact same error.

Comment: @HighCore: While your answer is a good description of the "WPF mentality" it does not address the specific problem in this question where a `BitmapSource` is created on another thread. The `BitmapSource` can be frozen which removes it's thread affinity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get the exception *Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject.* is an indication that the `BitmapSource` has been created on a new thread and you will not be able to bind the `BitmapSource` to the UI unless you create it on the UI thread. However, because `BitmapSource` is freezable you can also "freeze" it to remove it's thread affinity. So if you really need to create a `BitmapSource` on another thread you will have to call `Freeze` on the `BitmapSource` before you can bind it the UI.